# If A is a large number and B is a larger number than A, find C which is the nearest number to A that goes into B x times.

Tags: divisibility

```
A = 2548788451252366445785585474844745854781554558547847844

B = 50135928365972237608005364328936872115615930177019003323815

x is unknown
```

Given `A` and `B` find `C`, where `C` must be the nearest integer to `A` that goes into `B` `x` times.

Note: `C` must be smaller than `A` or equal with `A`.

Calculating `C` manually will involve subtracting or dividing `A` from `B` `x` times until we get near `A` and therefore to `C`.

Is there a formula or maybe a SageMath or PARI method to calculate `C`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide $B$ by $x$, then round down to the next whole number.  Any language that lets you handle integers this large will do that.  $A$ does not figure in this at all.

Based on the comment you are just asking for the remainder of the division of B by A.  Many languages have a modulo operator which will do this.  Often it is the percent sign, so you would write $C=B\%A$  You can do division with remainder in any language that can handle large integers.  If you can't do the modulo operation, you can do integer division and $C=B-\lfloor B/A\rfloor\cdot A$

Comment: Thanks, but [x] is unknown so I cannot use this method. I will update the question to mention this fact.

Comment: Then what are you trying to answer?  Are you actually looking for a number that divides $B$ exactly?  You should say that.

Comment: I'm looking for the closest number to A that goes into B x times. I don't know x because if I knew that this would have been a simple task to answer.

Comment: Yes, you said that.  Do you mean it has to divide exactly?  Otherwise it doesn't give any information to say "goes into $B\ x$ times" without knowing $x$

Comment: The division is most certainly not exact. There will be remainders. But if we substract let's say A from B many times we will eventually get to a C number that's closest to A. Doing this manually with large numbers is very difficult. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So with smaller numbers:  if A=111 and B=570 then we do 570-111-111-111-111-111=15

C=15 in this case. 

Not sure if I've explained correctly in the question but this number 15 is the nearest to 111 that is not larger than 111.  Maybe I am looking for a remainder but not sure if it's possible to calculate with larger numbers.